# How to prove that $f(x) =1/x$ is unbounded in $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f(x) = 1/x$ for all $x\in (0,1)$

By assuming $f(x)$ is bounded or in any other way but **without using limits**

I **assumed** that $f$ is bounded above, then there is $M>0$ s.t $f(x) \leq M$ for all $x$ in $(0,1)$.

$$1/x \leq M \implies  x \geq 1/M$$

Comment: You are on a good track. Is it true that $x\geq 1/M$ for all $x\in(0,1)$?

Comment: @Wojowu yes, M is an upper bound of  f(x)

Comment: Yes, keep going. If you thought you had a bound, you could always surpass it by taking $x$ small enough.

Comment: By definition, $f$ is bounded if and only if there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x\in (0,1)$, we have $|f(x)| < M$. 

So, by negating the above statement, we see that $f$ is unbounded iff  $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $x \in (0,1)$ such that $|f(x)| \geq n$. This can be achieved by taking $x=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I believe you're practically done. Maybe simply state f(x) > M for x < 1/M. There always exists a x for 0 < x < 1/M. Like x = 1/(2M)

Comment: yes you are right. but I've been asked for prove it by a contradiction which breaks the previous assumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. Let's assume $f(x)=1/x$ is bounded, therefore there exists $M>0$ such that $f(x)\leq M$ when $x\in(0,1)$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $M>1$ (since if $M$ were lesser than 1, any number greater than 1 would also be a bound).

This means that,

$1/x\leq M\implies 1\leq Mx$

The above equation is valid for any $x\in(0,1)$ and since $M>1$, $M+1>1$ and $\frac{1}{M+1}<1$. In particular $\frac{1}{M+1}\in (0,1)$, so if we pick $x=1/(M+1)$ the above inequality says that $1\leq \frac{M}{M+1}$.

But we also know that $M<M+1$ and therefore $\frac{M}{M+1}<1$ This contradicts the above inequality. Therefore $f(x)$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 8):

By definition, $f$ is bounded if and only if there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x\in (0,1)$, we have $|f(x)| < M$.

Assume that such an $M$ exists, now take $x=\frac{1}{M+1}$. Then $f(x)=M+1$ and $|f(x)| > M$. Contradiction.

Comment: I might not be following properly here, but in your second line you would end up with $\lvert M + 1 \rvert > M$ , which is true. So I think you want the inequality sign flipped around in the proof so that $\lvert f(x) \rvert < M$. This would lead to the desired contradiction.

Comment: @GrayLiterature What is meant is that $M+1=|f(x)| > M$ contradicts $|f(x)| < M$ which was implied by definition.

Answer (score 2):

It's lower bound is obviously $1$, it is a constantly decreasing function in the range and $f(1)=1$ is defined.

For the upper bound, assume that bound is $U=\frac{1}{x_0}$

Then evaluate $f(\frac{x_0}{2})$, we know $\frac{x_0}{2}<x_0$. Then apply the knowledge that for $a,b>0$ we have $$a>b\iff\frac ab> 1$$
What does this tell you?

Comment: your methid is right. but I've been asked to prove it by making a contradiction

Comment: This does exactly that. If $U$ is the upper bound, then $$\frac{f(t)}{U}\leq 1$$ holds for all $t$. Use $t=\frac{x_0}{2}$ to prove this doesn't hold.

Comment: ah, yes I got your point ✌